# Filter with a substring in binary array using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo-3.x

I want to filter the records which contains specific string in a field using pymongo. The filed is of type Binary array.

I also want to filter based on the date part of datetime. The filed is retrieved as datetime in python, but the type in Mongodb compass shows as array. For example, I want to get all the records with '2019-05-31' where the records are stored in datetime format and type is array
2019-05-31T22:49:15.722+00:00
[image]

Comment: Please add examples of these documents. The relevant fields only. It's not quite clear how  "2019-05-31T22:49:15.722+00:00" is an array.  Neither what is a binary array. There are arrays and binary data but these are 2 different types. There are only 19 data types that can be stored in mongo: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/

Comment: Added screenshot of Mongodb compass

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question  has a long list of reasons why "example of these documents" should be in the json format, not a screenshot. In this particular case there is one more - I cannot copy your image to https://mongoplayground.net/ and show you how the correct answer works. So please add the json.

Comment: ah, and one more thing, how do you want to filter the binary? "contains specific string" is about strings, not binaries. Please add the the example of the filter too.